# Get service start limit interval on apache

Tags: linux, systemd, apache2

I'm creating a program witch starts and stops the apache service multiple times to install an other program, on a default configuration with `StartLimitIntervalSec=10s` and `StartLimitBurst=5` it works well but some people edit those parameters and my program fails.

What I want is get the values and then adapt the program to "sleep" the good length of time between starting the service.

Is there a way to know those values without reading the config file ?

Comment: I may be dense but I just don't understand this question. Sorry.

Comment: When you try to start/stop a service multiple times too quickly, you'll get an error `service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start`, the solution to fix this is editing the systemd config `DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec` and `DefaultStartLimitBurst` and increase values. I can't do that because the script will be executed on different servers, what I want is to read those values and dynamically adapt my script to make pauses between the start requests